# How to debug an app with Electron and Angular from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, electron

I'm trying to develop a very simple app using the latest versions of Angular and Electron. For this, I followed the tutorials of Angular and Electron. After a lot of trial and error, finally I can start my application (source code on GitHub).
I use Visual Studio Code and when setting a breakpoint in my TypeScript code, it never get's hit when debugging my Electron application. For this, I've configured `launch.json` as follows:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\main.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                ".",
                "--enable-logging"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

My `tasks.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "npm run build",
            "type": "shell",
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
        }
    ]
}
```

The script `build` for the command `npm run build` is defined in my `package.json` and simply calls `ng build`. So after starting debugging, the output will be built into the `dist` folder and from there I start my Electron app.
Within the `dist` folder, there are also some `*.js.map` files, which (as far as I understood) should be responsible of acting as a bridge to the TypeScript files, right?

Any hints why my breakpoints are not working?

Comment: here is the link provided with all details: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/electron/electron_debugging.htm

Comment: Debugging of the JavaScript code works, but not the TypeScript code.

Comment: Did you resolve this?  Having similar issues saying it can't find my JavaScript even tho the maps are there.

Comment: No, unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 4):

Start the electron app using --remote-debug-port option. e.g. using 9222 as debug port:

```sh
electron . --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Then configure launch.json like that:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:9222",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```